# Get all instances of a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm trying to get the instances of a class, but I can't find a way to do it. The instances are created before my script loads, so I can't just make a variable that stores the instances. I've tried changing prototype methods, which does work for some classes that call the methods all the time, but not all of them do, and changing all of the methods is very annoying. So, **is there a way to get all the instances of a class, reliably and arbitrarily timed**?

Comment: This is impossible, it would make garbage collection not work

Comment: What do you need this for? What actual problem are you trying to solve by getting all instances? Why does your script load late?

Comment: It's a script that is like an extension (for example TamperMonkey) that loads into the website later to modify it. Also I saw Chrome's `queryObjects()` which means that it is definitely possible.

Comment: @soshimee_ that's a specific browser dev tool. Not something available for JS code you write. It's definitely not "definitely possible".

Comment: Yes, I mean it's definitely possible to implement, not to use.

Comment: It's possible to implement *for Chrome DevTools*. This isn't something somebody threw together in their spare time. It's using the fact that Chrome is hosting the V8 engine. It's not code that runs within the V8 engine the same as any other JS code.

Comment: The fact that the V8 engine is able to do it means it can is possible to implemented.

Comment: I don't think you understand where JS code runs. It's not *outside* the engine. It's *inside*. This facility is not exposed *inside*.

Answer (score 1):

No. JavaScript doesn't have any features that would make that possible.

Normally, I'd approach this by modifying the `constructor` of the class to include something like `instance_of_foo.push(this)` but you don't appear to have control over the source code of the class so that wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Are there any proposals for what I have described or is it just hopeless...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using a framework, but you could define an array in a place where all the needed callees have access to. There you can store the instance via the constructor.

Here is an example:

```
"use strict";

var exampleInstances = [];

class Example{
    prop = "";
    
    constructor() {
        this.prop = "Example"+exampleInstances.length;
        exampleInstances.push(this);
    }
}

var eInstance = new Example();
var eInstance2 = new Example();
var eInstance2 = new Example();

for (var i=0; i<exampleInstances.length; i++) {
    console.log(exampleInstances[i].prop);
}
```

Comment: The classes are created before my script loads.

Comment: ahh.. yes... .  Can you tell which system or what kind of framework you use, which generates your classes?

Comment: It's one of the native classes built into the browser.